# SQL condition with subquery return operand error

Tags: postgresql

I have a query which returns:

```
amount    id 
23414     21
234234    21
23434     21
235434    22
3453      22
345345    22
345345    22
```

I have another query which return:

```
{10,227,185,22,228,186,21,164}
```

I link the first query with the second with the following code:

```
SELECT first_query from first_data
where id in (SELECT array_agg(unnest::int) from (
            SELECT unnest(reg) from (
            SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(svals, '(\d+)=>', 'g') as reg
            FROM (SELECT svals(additional_infos) as svals from logs bl) as s
```

)

The error:

```
operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
```

Conclusion:
They are both integer and I want to get the rows where the id is IN the second query.
Any contribution would be appreciated.

EDIT:

The addition_infos column has the following type of data in each cell:

```
"ex_bal"=>"{11=>0.0, 14=>0.0, 263=>0.0}", "leg_bal"=>"{\"local\"=>142800.0, 221=>{\"network\"=>0.0}, 73=>{\"network\"=>1463970.84589323}}"
```

Comment: I think it would be better if **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data from the `logs` table and an explanation on what exactly you are trying to extract from the `hstore` column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have to use regex with this kind of value `{11=>0.0, 14=>0.0, 263=>0.0}`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes it is a hstore. Please look at the edit

Comment: You could make your life a **lot** easier, if you stored that in a json column which properly supports nesting values. This is a horrible mis-use of the hstore type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Probably, unfortunately this is not my choice..

Comment: That `SELECT array_agg(unnest::int) FROM (SELECT unnest(reg) FROM …` seems horribly overcomplicated. "*Conclusion: They are both integer*" - no, for some reason you were doing an `array_agg` so the subquery returns an array, not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

If your 'Second_Query' returns an array then you can use:

```
SELECT first_query from first_data WHERE id = ANY(SELECT second_query)
```